# Entire Angular 2 App doesn't load when accessed through domain name

Tags: angular, nginx, web-applications, dns

So I have been hitting my head since the past couple of days trying to fix this weird issue. Basically If I try accessing my Angular 2 app through a domain name (example.com), it will be stuck on the loading screen.

But If I try accessing the very same app without nginx, it loads the entire app just fine.

Plus the error in the browser console is "main.(some-random-numbers-and-alphabets).js not found (404). Even though the file exists in the same directory (/dist).

At this point I am not sure if there is an error with NGINX or with my Angular Build. Below is my NGINX configuration. Please suggest any solutions. Thanks.

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    # load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # www.example.com
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name www.example.com;
        root /var/www/example.com/public;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # security headers
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

        # . files
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        # assets, media
        location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
            expires 7d;
            access_log off;
        }

        # svg, fonts
        location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires 7d;
            access_log off;
        }

        # gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
    }

    # HTTP redirect
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name .example.com;

        # ACME-challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL is the site behind? Is it just `example.com`, or is it `example.com/mySite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you answers. I have actually figured out the issue and everything is working smoothly.

The solution is:-

```
 # . files
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }
```

Deleting the code above. Post that everything worked fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be with `dist` folder you had put into your site which is not recommendable and it will not work if your site folder doesn't point to `dist` folder directly. So what you can do is move your files of `dist` to `site folder` ( a level up from dist folder).